# How to use fromString() with currentDate()

Tags: c++, qt, date, format, qt5

I'm trying to get current date from the system clock and change its format (i.e. to this format `dd/MM/yyyy`). After that I need to set QDateEdit using `setDate()`. My problem is that using `fromString()` with `QDate::currentDate()` returns an invalid date. This is the piece of code regarding this issue

```
QDate date = QDate::currentDate().fromString("dd/MM/yyyy");
qDebug() << date.toString(); // <-- returns empty string 
StartDateEdit->setDate(date); // <-- adding invalid date shows 1-1-2000
```

My system clock has this format `M/d/yyyy` in Windows 10. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QDate::currentDate()` is a static function, this returns the current date, the object stores the date, not the format. If you want to display the form: `"dd/MM/yyyy"` you must use the `setDisplayFormat` function of `QDateEdit`.

```
QDate date = QDate::currentDate();
StartDateEdit->setDate(date);
StartDateEdit->setDisplayFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

*Note:The `fromString` function converts a string to QDate indicating the format of the string.*